# NHibernate mapping. Class name the same as property name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

In my NHibernate mapping file I've had two classes mapped where one classes property had the same name as another classes name (**Group**).

```
  <class name="Machine" table="SpisMaszyn" dynamic-update="true">
    <cache usage ="read-write"/>
    <id name="ID" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property column="NazwaMaszyny" name="MachineName" />
    <property column="Grupa" name="Group" />
  </class>


  <class name="Group" table="SpisGrup" dynamic-update="true">
    <cache usage ="read-write"/>
    <id name="ID" column="ID" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" column="Nazwa" />
  </class>
```

I don't know why but if the names are the same the code wasn't working properly. In my ModelState I was getting null value for Group. I'm not sure what can be causing it.

Do you have any idea what might cause this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping is correct. A fact that some property and some other class name share same name, is not any issue for NHibernate. Check the underlying column content. Run profiler to see the SQL Query and assure that returned data are there...

*original assumpiton that many-to-one is required removed*

Comment: This isn't reference. This is a normal property(string). I just named it the same as the class. I just don't know why this causes problems.

Comment: *Then sorry for my misunderstanding. Many-to-one is not needed.* BUT your mapping is correct. It is not a problem that property has the same name as some other class. I would guess, that the underlying column **"GRUPA"** is simply null or empty. Because mapping is CORRECT ;)

Comment: Yea I thought so as well but code started working after I changed the property name to GroupName. Now it's fine. This is really weird.

Comment: That would not be related to NHibernate. It could be that there is some other feature in your "framework" resetting that property... but NHibernate does not have problem at all if property is the same as some other mapped Class...

Comment: ok thanks a lot Radim. I'll try to look somewhere else than :)

Comment: Good luck with NHibernate sir, it is great tool ;)